# IF & IF OR & AND IF Statements (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to create an automated checker. If people choise the rights answers from a Dropdown box they will see the msg: "You May Now Consult" if not they will see "You shall not pass"

I have the following code:

=IF(OR(C8="1", "2")*(D8="Yes")*(E8="Yes")*(G8="Reusable")*(F8="Yes"),  "You May now Consult", "You Shall Not Pass")

The issue is just the first part, C8. Since it's a dropdown box people can choise multiple answers.

Imagine there are the numbers 1-5 in the dropdown box, but I only want the true statement to be if they choise 1 or 2. The issue now is If I put in number 3 it will give me the error code #VALUE! error.

How Could i create this code so that if they choose numbers 3-5 it will give the error msg "You Shall not Pass"?

Sorry for my explanation as I never really coded anything and this is my first project.

Thanks in advance!

Tried to add the IF(NOT statement but it does not seem to match with the (IF(OR statement.

Comment: So the issue why it's happening just on the first part (C8) is because they have multiple options, they can choose either 1 or 2.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The syntax in your formula is easy to fix, but it is unclear what the semantics should be. What do you want the formula to do in different scenarios? Give several examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix syntax errors in the formula like this:

```
=if( 
  or( C8 = "1", C8 = "2", D8 = "Yes", E8 = "Yes", G8 = "Reusable", F8 = "Yes"), 
  "You May now Consult", 
  "You Shall Not Pass" 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it like this now: =IF(OR(C8="1", "2", D8="Yes", E8="Yes", G8="Reusable", F8="Yes"), "You May now Consult", "You Shall Not Pass") However I still get the same error when picking number 3 at C8: OR expects boolean values. But '3' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean.

Comment: Use `C8 = "3"` instead of `"3"`.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, :) much appreciated. I'm not quite sure what you mean with that. I want to get the response You Shall not pass whenever someone picked number 3 at c8.

Comment: I got this now: =IF(OR(C8="1", C8="2", D8="Yes", E8="Yes", G8="Reusable", F8="Yes"), "You May now Consult", "You Shall Not Pass") But the issue is now that if they pick for example number 3 at c8 it will still show as correct, while it should not be.

Comment: Start with `=IF(OR(C8="1", C8="2"),"You May now Consult", "You Shall Not Pass")`. And I think you should remove the quotes around 1 and 2: `OR(C8=1, C8=2)`, unless they're really strings. I'm not sure you want the other conditions (involving D9, E8, etc).

Comment: The syntax in your formula is easy to fix, but it is unclear what the semantics should be. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74723062/edit) the question and tell what do you want the formula to do in different scenarios. Give several examples.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF((C8="1")+(C8="2")+(D8="Yes")+(E8="Yes")+(G8="Reusable")+(F8="Yes"), 
 "You May now Consult", "You Shall Not Pass")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula:

```
IF(
 OR(
  C8=1,
  C8=2,
  D8="Yes",
  E8="Yes",
  G8="Reusable",
  F8="Yes"
 ),
 "You May now Consult",
 "You Shall Not Pass"
)
```

When you use an `OR()` function, it returns true whenever any of the conditions are matched, in you case, either `C8` is `1` or `2`, or `D8` or `E8` or  `F8` is `"Yes"`, or `G8` is `"Reusable"`.

So, even if you put a `3` into `C8`, if there are `"Yes"` in any of `D8:F8`, or `"Reusable"` is shown in `G8`, it will still returns `TRUE`.

But if the value of `C8` must be `1` or `2`, in that case, you need a `AND()`:

```
IF(
 AND(
  OR(
   C8=1,
   C8=2,
  ),
  OR(
   D8="Yes",
   E8="Yes",
   G8="Reusable",
   F8="Yes"
  )
 ),
 "You May now Consult",
 "You Shall Not Pass"
)
```

With this formula, it will return `TRUE` only when `C8` is equal to `1` or `2` AND either `D8:F8` contains a `"Yes"` or `G8` equals to `"Reusable"`